# How to address this issue, APK or AAB is using permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.CAMERA)

Tags: android, react-native

**Your APK or Android App Bundle is using permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.CAMERA).**

> In my AndroidManifest.xml file i already request the CAMERA
> Permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

But still i got this error.
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to provide a link of your **Privacy Policy** for your app in Google Play console

You can provide a privacy policy to your app by navigating to:

> Play Console -> Your App -> App Content -> Privacy Policy -> A field where you should give your URL link

And to generate a Privacy policy (If you don't have any) you can use online privacy policy generator.

> Ex: [Privacy policy generator](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/)

**Now to host your privacy policy. You can do any of this:**

If you have a server you can host the file in your server and use that link. If not then there is some other way to make your work done.

1. You may put your file in git then use that link
2. You can just create a doc with your policy text in your Google Drive and then select File-> Publish for web, you will get a link to share. Use that link